# The view function for 'run' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I did write an HTTP Cloud Function in the Google Cloud Platform. The purpose of this function is to update data in the Database (Firestore).

I do not intend to return something from this trigger. At least not directly. The updated data is getting fetched with a stream.

Although the Cloud Function does exactly what I want, I get in the logs the following error:

```
The view function for 'run' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Do I always have to return something? What would be good practice for this case?

**Update:**

In the end I just used the following json object

```
return '{"status":"200", "data": "OK"}'
```

I am not satisfied with my solution, but for the time it will do.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#terminating_http_functions), these may create background tasks (threads, futures, Promises, etc) as it seems to be your case. When this happnes you must terminate or resolve these tasks before you return an HTTP response.

Also, you need to make sure that you send an HTTP response when these Cloud Functions are [HTTP-triggered](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#ensure_http_functions_send_an_http_response).

Failing to the aforementioned may cause unpredictable behavior, latency and some messages in logs like the one you found.

If you want to terminate background or HTTP functions, this code from [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime).

Background functions:

```
// Await-ing promises within functions is OK if you do not return anything
await Promise.resolve();
 
// These will cause background tasks to stop executing immediately
return 1; // OK: returning a value
return await Promise.resolve(); // WRONG: returning the result of a promise
return await Promise.reject(); // WRONG: same behavior as resolved promises
 
// These will wait until the related background task finishes
return Promise.resolve(); // OK: returning the promise itself
return Promise.reject(); // OK: same behavior as to-be-resolved promises
```

HTTP Functions

```
// OK: await-ing a Promise before sending an HTTP response
await Promise.resolve();
 
// WRONG: HTTP functions should send an
// HTTP response instead of returning.
return Promise.resolve();
 
// HTTP functions should signal termination by returning an HTTP response.
// This should not be done until all background tasks are complete.
res.send(200);
res.end();
 
// WRONG: this may not execute since an
// HTTP response has already been sent.
return Promise.resolve();
```

I hope this information helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Froilan. Thanks for the answer. I am working with Python, so I am unsure as to how much I can use this. What I finally did, was the following: return '{"status":"200", "data": "OK"}' and the message did disappear...

Answer (score 0):

If a function creates background tasks (in your case it's a Promise object when updating Firestore), you must terminate or otherwise resolve these tasks before returning an HTTP response.

Comment: So does this mean I have to await the "background tasks" before ending the function? Since everything goes as planned, I guess I should resolve these tasks. How does one generally resolve a Promise in Python before returning an HTTP response?